# How to get Audio file through HTTP get?

Tags: java, android, audio, streaming, restful-architecture

I am trying to get an Audio file through http get from a secure restful service, I have successfully receive and parse text XML service but a bit confused that how to do with Audio file.

code to call the secure restful service with XML response

```
String callWebService(String serviceURL) {
        // http get client
        HttpClient client = getClient();
        HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet();

        try {
            // construct a URI object
            getRequest.setURI(new URI(serviceURL));
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            Log.e("URISyntaxException", e.toString());
        }

        // buffer reader to read the response
        BufferedReader in = null;
        // the service response
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            // execute the request
            response = client.execute(getRequest);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.e("ClientProtocolException", e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("IO exception", e.toString());
        }
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity()
                    .getContent()));
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.e("IllegalStateException", e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("IO exception", e.toString());
        }
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        try {
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                buff.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("IO exception", e.toString());
            return e.getMessage();
        }

        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("IO exception", e.toString());
        }
        // response, need to be parsed
        return buff.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may this one help you..

```
public static void downloadFile(String fileURL, String fileName) {
    try {
        // fileURL=fileURL.replaceAll("amp;", "");
        Log.e(fileURL, fileName);
        String RootDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .toString();

        File RootFile = new File(RootDir);
        new File(RootDir + Commons.dataPath).mkdirs();
        File file = new File(RootFile + Commons.dataPath + fileName);
        if (file.exists()) {

            file.delete();
        }
        file.createNewFile();

        URL u = new URL(fileURL);
        HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
        c.setDoOutput(true);
        c.connect();
        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                "mnt/sdcard"+Commons.dataPath + fileName));
        InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len1 = 0;

        while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            f.write(buffer, 0, len1);
        }
        f.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```